# android carousel like gallery

Tags: android, android-view

Hi i want to display Caoursel like Gallery almost CarouselView in IPhone with rotatory property i find two projects from google which consists of render script

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) and [this](http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/ex/carousel/java/com/android/ex/carousel)

but my requirement is something like this. I dont want to show the back view but it should be in 3d format. I tried hard but no luck.[image]

I tried to customize above projects but no luck for me.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: what you tried can you post that code.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel  with in this project i changed the angle.Here in this project i'm getting views back and front like circle also i tried changing values. i'm not understanding what and where to change.First i request that whether this can be achievable using this project.My requirement i should see only front views but motion should be like circle

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [this](http://code.google.com/p/my-first-android-app/source/browse/de.vogella.android.tempconvertor/src/com/example/coverflow/CoverFlow.java?r=6) link and you need to make some modification

```
  /**
     * The maximum angle the Child ImageView will be rotated by
     */    
    private int mMaxRotationAngle = 60;<------------here 

    /**
     * The maximum zoom on the centre Child
     */
    private int mMaxZoom = -120;<------------here
```

as per your requirment

[Android Coverflow Widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

I changed these two variable and it was looking as below

![enter image description here][3]

Comment: Thanks for reply check and let you know the response

Comment: i checked that cover flow it is not exactly the same but in that project zoom Level applying to every view but i need only center view should be zoomed and other should shrink their sizes.how to achieve this.can you help me in that if possible

Comment: Can you attach the output image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12239/discussion-between-manju-and-dheeresh-singh)

Comment: may i know which values you are using for that and views angle is changing instead of angle change is that anyway only to change size of views and to increase the size of center so that it looks exactly the same

Comment: And one more thing is that possible to decrease the size exponentially according to size next to left<left<Center>right>next to right like this